# Sql Trend line by departments

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using the example of how to create a sql trend line on a report using the below link.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3432/add-a-linear-trendline-to-a-graph-in-sql-server-reporting-services/

I've got it all up and running but I want to work out the trend by departments also. However its just merging all the data into one final value, I think its the below section of code that needs altering to calculate the sum by each of the departments I add in, but how best do I do this?

```
-- calculate sample size and the different sums
SELECT
  @sample_size = COUNT(*)
 ,@sumX   = SUM(ID)
 ,@sumY   = SUM([OrderQuantity])
 ,@sumXX   = SUM(ID*ID)
 ,@sumYY   = SUM([OrderQuantity]*[OrderQuantity])
 ,@sumXY   = SUM(ID*[OrderQuantity])
FROM #Temp_Regression;

-- output results
SELECT
  SampleSize   = @sample_size  
 ,SumRID    = @sumX   
 ,SumOrderQty   =@sumY   
 ,SumXX    = @sumXX   
 ,SumYY    = @sumYY   
 ,SumXY    = @sumXY;
```

These variables are then used to work out the trend line:

```
-- calculate the slope and intercept
SET @slope = CASE WHEN @sample_size = 1
    THEN 0 -- avoid divide by zero error
    ELSE (@sample_size * @sumXY - @sumX * @sumY) / (@sample_size * @sumXX - POWER(@sumX,2))
    END;
SET @intercept = (@sumY - (@slope*@sumX)) / @sample_size;
```

Comment: Is there any department related column in given table?

Comment: Yes in the temp table I have a column called department, the data is all being filtered by department and the ID ive used a row_number on to get unique numbers for each group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `departments` column in `SELECT` & `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT departments,
       SampleSize = Count(*),
       SumRID = Sum(ID),
       SumOrderQty = Sum([OrderQuantity]),
       SumXX = Sum(ID * ID),
       SumYY = Sum([OrderQuantity] * [OrderQuantity]),
       SumXY = Sum(ID * [OrderQuantity])
FROM   #Temp_Regression
GROUP  BY departments
```

Here is the easier way to calculate `slope` & `intercept` for all departments

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT departments,
                sample_size = Count(*),
                sumX = Sum(ID),
                sumY = Sum([OrderQuantity]),
                sumXX = Sum(ID * ID),
                sumYY = Sum([OrderQuantity] * [OrderQuantity]),
                sumXY = Sum(ID * [OrderQuantity])
         FROM   #Temp_Regression
         GROUP  BY departments),
     slope
     AS (SELECT departments,
                Sample_Size,
                sumX,
                sumY,
                slope = CASE
                          WHEN sample_size = 1 THEN 0 -- avoid divide by zero error
                          ELSE ( sample_size * sumXY - sumX * sumY ) / ( sample_size * sumXX - Power(sumX, 2) )
                        END
         FROM   cte)
SELECT departments,
       slope,
       intercept = ( sumY - ( slope * sumX ) ) / sample_size
FROM   slope
```

Comment: I tried this solution first but it gives the following error: A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Comment: @user3691566 Then you made some changes to the above query . Dont assign the columns to variables

Comment: The variables are used later on to work out the trend line calculation though. I've used the original post to show the later part of the query where the variables are referenced.

Comment: @user3691566 Then you may have to loop the result. Post calculation logic will change it to set based to approach

Comment: Yes i did try it with one department that that worked so will see about adding a loop in, was hoping there was a simpler solution to try first

Comment: this looks like its going to do what i needed thanks